# Не выходит сохранить formset_factory в django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

В models.py

```
class Recipes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=5000)

class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=5000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductsInRecipes(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipes)
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(10000)],
        blank=False,
        null=False)
```

В forms.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import forms
from recipes.models import Recipes, ProductsInRecipes

class RecipesAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipes
        fields = ('name', 'text')

class ProductsInRecipesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductsInRecipes
        fields = ('product', 'weight')
```

В views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from recipes.forms import RecipesAddForm, ProductsInRecipesForm


def add(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = RecipesAddForm()
    args['form2'] = formset_factory(
        ProductsInRecipesForm, extra=2, max_num=30, validate_max=True)
    if request.POST:
        form = RecipesAddForm(request.POST)
        ProuctsFormSet = formset_factory(ProductsInRecipesForm)
        form2 = ProuctsFormSet(request.POST)
        args['form'] = form
        args['form2'] = form2
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            recipe = form.save(commit=False)
            recipe.autor = request.user
            recipe.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            for product in form2:
                product.save(commit=False)
                product.recipe = recipe
                product.save()
            return redirect('/ok/')
        return render_to_response('recipes_add.html', args, RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('recipes_add.html', args, RequestContext(request))
```

И шаблон recipes_add.html

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div id="content" class="lr_auto">
    <form id="add_recipes_form" method="post" action="/recipes/add/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        {% for form in form2 %}
            {{form.product}}
            {{form.weight}}
        {% endfor %}
        {{form2.management_form}}
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

При нажатии на submit ошибка:
NOT NULL constraint failed: productsInRecipes.recipe_id

Данные из form сохраняются, а из form2 соответственно нет.
Как правильно сохранить form2 или что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну судя по ошибке проблема видимо в том, что в ProductsInRecipes у тебя есть recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipes), а в ProductsInRecipesForm это поле никак не заполняется.

Comment: product.recipe = recipe   а разве этого мало? так же пробовал product.recipe = 1 и подставлять другие значения...

Comment: А разве в модели product. есть поле recipe?

Comment: product от модели ProductsInRecipes, там есть recipe

Comment: Согласен, не внимательно посмотрел. 
А эта строка 
    `form.save_m2m()`
точно корректна ?

Comment: Да корректна, там еще поле many_to_many было но тут я её вырезал что бы было проще код читать, её можно проигнорировать. ибо там есть еще 2 модели National и Categories связанные с Recipes при помощи m2m

Comment: Похоже ваш случай:
[ссылка](http://djbook.ru/rel1.4/topics/forms/modelforms.html)

Примечание
Если вы указываете fields или exclude при создании формы через ModelForm, то поля, которые не определены в форме, не будут учитываться при вызове метода save(). Также, если вы вручную добавите в форму исключенные поля, то они не будут заполняться из экземпляра модели.

Django будет препятствовать всем попыткам сохранить неполную модель. Таким образом, если модель требует заполнения определённых полей и для них не предоставлено значение по умолчанию, то сохранить форму для такой модели не получится.

Comment: добавил в ProductsInRecipes.recipe значение default = 1 теперь все записи идут с значением recipes 1, понять бы как это переопределить при сохранении формы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если всё правильно понимаю проблема вот в этом куске кода

`product.save(commit=False)`

куда ты сохраняешь результат? он у тебя в воздухе весит, соответственно далее ты работаешь уже не с объектом модели, а всё с той же формой:

```
product.recipe = recipe
product.save()
```

Учись правильно формировать названия переменных и не будет таких проблем:

```
for product_form in form2:
    product = product_form.save(commit=False)
    product.recipe = recipe
    product.save()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Конечно за это время я решил задачу несколько иначе, удалив вообще промежуточную модель, но на будущее мне это будет отличным уроком. Ваше решение верное.